# Setting CustomAdapter for NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, custom-adapter

I have integrated Navigation drawer in my app.The issue is that CustomAdapter is not showing the content.However if i use default ArrayAdapter content is shown.I failed to understand where am I going wrong in setting CustomAdapter.

Comment: try to log optionList[position] values . is it really equal?

Comment: @N5. i think its never going inside getView() of adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add below api to tell listview the total number of rows in listview :

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return optionList.length;
    }
```